# How to understand the query that originates from Oracle and must use Bind-variable SSIS Source managed?

Tags: oracle, ssis, etl

I need to run a query in SSIS Package (Dataflow->Source->SQL Command)
I use it, which should be filtered by Bind-Variables so that in terms of speed, the Oracle search in the list of Child Cursors is done quickly and as a result, the output is done faster. In fact, I need the query to be written as Bind-Variable (I emphasize that the parameter used in dynamic query must be passed to a variable and that variable must be defined as bind-variable)

variable V_param number
exec :V_param := 10 /*10 Pass From Variable To V_param*/
Select * from XXXXX where Field_x = :V_param;

The above query should return a Record-Set, so that in the Data-Flow part and the transfer of its data from the source to the destination is done by Bulk Insert, but unfortunately the Record-Set is not returned and.....